# How can I make Python's 'webbrowser' block execution?

Tags: python, flask, soundcloud

I want to implement a Python script to act as my OAuth2 endpoint, since I'm trying to write a Soundcloud app. Part of the authentication process involves visiting a Soundcloud page where you can sign in and grant access to the given Soundcloud application.

I'd like to be able to open that webpage in a browser using Python 3, which you can do with the webbrowser object. You can see on the documentation that launching a text-based browser blocks execution; I want to block execution whilst the webpage is open in a GUI-based browser.

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Comment: No. For example, if Firefox is already running on Linux, the second invocation just sends the message to the first instance and exists immediately.

Comment: You ought to have responded with an answer since what you've said seems to check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be impossible to do portably. For example, if Firefox is already running on Linux, the second invocation of `firefox http://url` will find out that an instance using the same profile, will send a message to the other process to open that URL in a tab, then exits immediately.

---

However, you could accomplish the same thing by sending the authentication tokens to a server, and simultaneously polling the server for credentials in the python script.

Comment: This is what I implemented so far re: polling, but I just thought it was a little messy :) thanks Antti!